# When you are using VMWare`s share folder to develop node.js project, how to node_modules file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vmware, vmware-workstation

1. I am using Windows computer, and my project must run at Linux. So I must use VM.
2. I also want to use WebStorm. JB Gateway has so many bugs so I don`t want to use it.

So I chosed VMWare share folder function. But unfortunally, unlike Golang, Ruby or other languages, nodejs dependencies will be installed at project folder. Which means If I execute `npm install`, Linux will try to write files to my share folder.

I tried to use `NODE_PATH`. In most situation it works. But if you want to use something like angular-cli to boot your project, it doesnt work.

So, how could I download `node_modules` file properly in VMWare share folder.

Comment: node_modules folder is only required at build time so you should be able to put it in the same folder as your source code

Comment: @DustinSpengler Does this approach work for deps which uses C++ addons?

Comment: @DustinSpengler I used `sqlite3` package in my project, and it won`t work. I must install packages in current system.

Comment: @DustinSpengler I think I found a way to resolve it. Run `npm rebuild sqlite3` can build current system`s .node file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install node_modules at Windows.
2. Run `npm rebuild xxx` for deps which are using C++ addons in VMWare.